# VSCode: "keybindings.json" not working as expected for terminal command

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, terminal, action, vscode-debugger

I am trying to run node on my computer through VSCode. It's installed in Unity's directory, because my school doesn't let us download random applications. But we use Unity for a class, and it has node.exe somewhere in it's directory in `Program Files`. I tried using that as the compiler path when I press `Ctrl + F5`, but I need NVM for that, which I don't have. So I tried making a direct command to do this, although I got stuck:

I will provide my `keybindings.json` file, my `index.js` file, and the terminal output.

#### keybindings.json

(The double slashes are escape for the text string.)

```json
[{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+f5",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "when": "editorLangId == javascript",
    "args": { "text": "cls; cd 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity 2022.3.6f1\\Editor\\Data\\Tools\\nodejs'; .\\node \"${file}\"; cd \"${fileDirname}\"; echo \u000D; pause" }
}]
```

#### index.js

```js
console.log('test');
```

#### Output

When I press `Left Shift + Ctrl + F5`, this happens:

```
test

cmdlet Write-Output at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:       
InputObject[0]:
```

It works, but it's looking for input. That's weird, because when I do it in Powershell and replace the `file` and `fileDirname` with the actual paths, it works as expected.

I want the output to be `test` followed by the newline.

I tried some things, like removing `pause`. That didn't work. When I remove the echo for the newline escape character, it ONLY puts the line in the terminal, but it doesn't run it. I think that might be causing the problem, but I believe `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence` is supposed to run the command and not just input it into the terminal.

One more thing that I can probably fix on my own, is that I have to have the terminal open to do this. If it's not currently open, it won't work.

Comment: "_but I need NVM for that_" for what exactly? and why?

Comment: what's the purpose of the echo? to run the command? why can't you just use `\n`? and what's up with the `pause` command? what's that for?

Comment: also... why don't you just use the `runtimeExecutable` property of your node launch config?- assuming you are using launch configs to run/debug.

Comment: @starball Unity that I have uses a degraded version of Node. VSCode won't let me use that without NVM for some reason.

Comment: @starball I don't know, `\n` seemed to do the exact same thing.

Comment: @starball And for your last question, I don't really get what you mean by `runtimeExecutable` because I am new to Node (I came from browser JS, slightly different from Node JS with all the packages and stuff) . Can you tell me what that is? [-----](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255593/discussion-between-dacuteraccoon-and-starball)